# Not able to start RabbitMQ source in Flink 1.3.2

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to start a RabbitMQ source and then sink, but I not able to perform first step i.e starting  Rabbit MQ source . RabbitMQ server is running and I can see dashboard as well.

My code is as below

public class rabbitmq_source {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    StreamExecutionEnvironment envrionment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();


     RMQConnectionConfig connectionConfig = new RMQConnectionConfig.Builder()
            .setHost("localhost")
            .setPort(50000).
                    setUserName("root")
             .setPassword("root").
                    setVirtualHost("/").build();


     DataStream<String> stream = envrionment
            .addSource(new RMQSource<String>(
                    connectionConfig,            // config for the RabbitMQ connection
                    "queue",                 // name of the RabbitMQ queue to consume
                    new SimpleStringSchema()));

    stream.print();

    envrionment.execute();



}
```

}

I am not sure what username and pass should I set, should they be `guest` and `guest`. However, I am getting the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create RMQ connection with queue at localhost
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.rabbitmq.RMQSource.open(RMQSource.java:172)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:36)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.open(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:111)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.openAllOperators(StreamTask.java:376)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:253)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:702)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.FrameHandlerFactory.create(FrameHandlerFactory.java:32)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:588)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:612)
```

Comment: same problem here. did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I considered using Kafka as using RabbitMQ was not necessary in my case

Answer (score 0):

Use `LocalStreamEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment()` with `guest` username and password.